# Sharepoint 2010 Folder in Custom List

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, folder

I would like to have folders in my custom list in order to have a form of archiving.  I was able to enable the folders by going to List Settings -> Advance Settings -> 'Make New Folder command available'

What I am currently unable to accomplish is moving the files (items in the list) that I have into that folder. Is there a way of accomplishing this task? It would seem trivial, but apparently it is not...Would I create a workflow or a view to put them in the folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about a list or a library? You would not normally use folders in a list. And you would not have files in a list either.

Comment: I'm talking about a list. I have items in the list I would like to archive.

Answer (score 1):

Create a column for the status of the item. Change the status to "archived" for archived items.
Change the default view and all other active views to include only items where status is not equal to "archived".
Create another view to show only archived items.

That way, you do not need folders in the list. Folders are not really meant for lists.

[edit:] for details about handling large lists with SharePoint 2010 see [Manage lists and libraries with many items](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010377496.aspx)

Comment: The thing is that my list is reaching the 5,000 limit. So I would like a way to archive the items without deleting them. I was informed that folders could be an option. Thanks.

Comment: A SharePoint list can hold millions of items, not just 5000. The magic 5000 is for **processing** and SQL related, not for storage. You can create views that don't show more than 5000 items. Use filters and indexed columns and the 5000 limit won't be a problem. Just make sure that no view includes "all items" unfiltered. I added a link to a Microsoft article above.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Site Actions -> Manage Content and Structure

Click on the name of your list and its items will be displayed on the right side.

Select the items you want to move, and click Actions -> Move, and now you can select your folder as the destination.

Comment: I do not have the "Manage Content & Structure" option

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cdbce5ec-0108-47eb-9f10-7eaa1cf79a0b/manage-content-and-structure-is-missing) can help.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this blog [post](http://www.orinoco-systems.com/blog/bid/109870/SharePoint-2010-copy-or-moving-multiple-files). You may also want to have a look at [in-place records Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363732%28v=office.14%29.aspx) capability of SharePoint 2010.

Comment: I did look at the blog, and that blog seems to be just for documents. The Custom List does not seem to have an explorer view. Also the Content Organizer mentioned in the records Managements only works for document folders. I have a custom list.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers).