# Lists structure,usage and search in SharePoint

Tags: list, search, content-type, query

I have some `requirements` items that can have multiple `tests` and each test can have `data sets` and each data set may/ may not have `defects`. How do I structure this as a list and not think of it as a relational db?

1. Do I maintain each as a list or each as a content type?
2. What makes searching easier?

What's the SharePoint way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a List and create folders for Each **requirement** folder and then  **tests** folder followed by **data sets** and **defects** item. In this way your data will be organized form.

So to have a defect item, It should be placed as follows:

Requirements Folder > Tests Folder > DataSets Folder > Defect Item.

To create a folder in Lists please check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70564/sharepoint-2010-folder-in-custom-list) link

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query